# How to acces the text (or its length) from <input> tag from itself?

Tags: html, dom, input, tags

Is it possible to access the text length in the `<input>` tag from itself?
Avoiding `document.getElementById("filter").value.length`

I want to do something like this:

```
<input id="filter" class="input" type="text" oninput="filterWhenTextLengthIs15(this.length)"/>
```

Is there something like `this.length`?

Comment: "*...Avoiding `document.getElementById("filter").value.length`*" - why?

Comment: `this.value.length`?  think `this` in the way you use it would be the input

Comment: @DavidThomas is is not slow to access the documents object, the the method and the twice the some fields in comparison to just one acces to this.length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get the length of the value (the text in the input) you have to use:

```
this.value.length
```

For your code:

`<input id="filter" class="input" type="text" oninput="filterWhenTextLengthIs15(this.value.length)"/>`